# How to update webpack.config file

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-spark

I am upgrading Laravel Spark from version 3 to 4.

Whenever I run `npm run dev`, I get the error...

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.output.path: The provided value "public" is not an absolute path!
>      -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).

I have [traced](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/16) this back to a need to update the webpack.config.js file, but I don't understand how to update this. Is it something that I need to do in npm? Is there a link to the config file that should go with the new version of webpack?

I tried fixing the output path like below, but it didn't work. I think that much of the file needs to change, but I am not sure in what way.

```
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            publicPath: '/app/'
        }
```

Comment: See the docs - your output path needs to be absolute, not relative: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#output

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried that and it didn't work. Updated the post

Comment: Did you try upgrading laravel mix ? in package.json